# How to find the value which minimises the residual sum of squares

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have 3 equations with 3 parameters(unknowns). I would to solve it using newton raphson method. I want to use initial values (parameters) for the Newton Raphson
procedure as the value (parameters) which
minimizes the residual sum of squares . how can i solve these equations. The parameters alpha,beta ang gamma >0.

```
  Eq1 = \[Sigma]*(1 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1)*Gamma[\[Beta] + 1] - 
      3.69348
    EQ2 = \[Sigma]*((1 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1) - 
         2*(2 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1))*Gamma[\[Beta] + 1] - 2.0520
    EQ3 = \[Sigma]*((1 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1) - 
         6*(2 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1) + 
         2*(3 - \[Alpha])^-(\[Beta] + 1))*Gamma[\[Beta] + 1] - 1.134
```

Comment: These are not equations but definitions of `Eq1, EQ2, EQ3`. These  `Eq1 == 0, ..., EQ3 == 0` might be equations.

Answer (score 1):

You probably first want to `Rationalize` the equations:

```
EQ1 = Rationalize[σ*(1 - α)^-(β + 1)*Gamma[β + 1] - 3.69348, 0];
EQ2 = Rationalize[σ*((1 - α)^-(β + 1) - 2*(2 - α)^-(β + 1))*Gamma[β + 1] - 2.0520, 0];
EQ3 = Rationalize[σ*((1 - α)^-(β + 1) - 6*(2 - α)^-(β + 1) + 2*(3 - α)^-(β + 1))*Gamma[β + 1] - 1.134, 0];
```

Then because $\alpha$ looks like a problematic parameter, plot the minimum of `EQ1^2 + EQ2^2 + EQ3^2` given values of $\alpha$:

```
LogPlot[FindMinimum[EQ1^2 + EQ2^2 + EQ3^2, {σ, β}][[1]], {\Alpha], -2, 5}]
```

[image: Plot of minimums given alpha]

So a plausible minimum value would seem to occur near $\alpha=1$.

Comment: `NMinimize[{Total[Rationalize[{Eq1, Eq2, Eq3}]^2], α < 1, β > -1}, {α, β, σ}, WorkingPrecision -> 21] // N`

Comment: @jimb @bob-hanlon
 I want to solve the above equations using newton method. I have to choose the initial value as the value (params) which minimizes the residual sum of squares . The params (α, β and σ) must be >0. When I tried the estimates that I got using above code in newton , I'm getting -ve estimates.
`sol = Module[{s = 0, e = 0}, {FindRoot[{Eq1 == 0, Eq2 == 0, Eq3 == 0}, {{\[Alpha], 0.41}, {\[Beta], 0.6}, {\[Sigma], 1.18}}, WorkingPrecision -> 21, StepMonitor :> s++,  EvaluationMonitor :> e++], "Steps" -> s, "Evaluations" -> e}] `
Not sure with the code.